# Read CSV File and Store Data In XML File

Tags: php, xml, csv

Hello i have This code

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);


function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=';')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}



$csvFile = "example.csv";

$csv = csv_to_array($csvFile);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';



$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$root = $xml->createElement("CATEGORY");
$domAttribute = $xml->createAttribute('name');
// Value for the created attribute
$domAttribute->value = 'Clear Skin 100ml Massage Oil 100ml-massage-oils';
// Don't forget to append it to the element
$root->appendChild($domAttribute);
$xml->appendChild($root);

foreach ($csv as $key => $value) {
     $book = $xml->createElement("PRODUCT");
    foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
     echo $key. " ==> " . $value."<br>";



     $key   = $xml->createElement($key);
    $value = $xml->createTextNode($value);
    $key->appendChild($value);



    $book->appendChild($key);

    }
     $root->appendChild($book);
}

$xml->formatOutput = true;
    echo "<xmp>". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";

    $xml->save("final.xml") or die("Error");
```

I have created this script to fetch data from csv file and store in xml file .  but i am haveing wrong output

my output :

```
Category ==> SMALL HOME APPLIANCES
Market ==> Breakfast
Segment ==> Hot beverage systems
PIXpro SKU ==> 19392107
```

it's not printing all the data from csv file but when i deleting

```
 $key   = $xml->createElement($key);
    $value = $xml->createTextNode($value);
    $key->appendChild($value);
    $book->appendChild($key);
```

this code then i am getting all data echo just fine can any help me

Comment: You are overwriting the `$value` variable while you're looping over it:  `foreach ($value as $key => $value)` - that's why. Don't use the same variable for different things. Here it helps to use more specific names than just `$value` (value of what?) or `$key` (key of what)?

Comment: i have two csv file one that is seperated with "," and other with ";"  , the csv file with "," is working fine with this code but when i am adding file with ";" this is having problem i just try to  rename the file as you told but still same :(

Comment: I did not suggest to rename the file but the variable. that's a whole different thing. and for the , or ; - that you need to tell the CSV parser you use. I normally use `SplFileObject` for CSV parsing.